# Jacobian for different variables

Tags: r, function, nested, ode

A differential equation might be defined as

```
sys <- function(t, y, p, u) {
  dy <- numeric(2)
  u <- u(t)

  dy[1] = p$a*(1 + p$b*(y[2] - 1)/(p$c + y[2] - 1) - u*y[1])
  dy[2] = u*y[1] - y[2]
  list(dy)
}
```

Let's furthermore assume that the steady states (equilibria) are known. Now, is there a way to calculate the Jacobian matrix of the right hand side of with respect to `x`?

I know that I could define

```
f <- function(y){
  c(
    p$a*(1 + p$b*(y[2] - 1)/(p$c + y[2] - 1) - u*y[1]),
    u*y[1] - y[2]
    )
}
```

and calculate the Jacobian with

```
Jx <- jacobian(f, c(1,1))
```

wherein `jacobian` comes from the `pracma` package. But isn't there an easier way without that intermediate step? It might also help if one could call `f` within `sys`, e.g.

```
sys <- function(t, y, p, u) {
  dy <- numeric(2)
  u <- u(t)

  dy[1] = f(y)[1]
  dy[2] = f(y)[2]
  list(dy)
}
```

And lastly, might there also be a way to calculate the Jacobian w.r.t. to `u`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What function is `u()`?

Comment: Some arbitrary function depending on time. Could be a line or an exponential or a sine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution with the **R** package [`rootSolve`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/index.html).

For this, your function definition has to be a little bit different, but (in my opinion) more convenient. I don't know your exact parameters `p` or your function `u`, so I made a minimal example:

```
library(rootSolve)
sys <- function(t, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(y,parms)),{

  dy = a*(1 + b*(z - 1)/(c + z - 1) - 1*y)
  dz = 1*y - z
  return(list(c(dy, dz)))
  })
}

parms <- list(a = 1, b = 1, c= 2)

rootSolve::jacobian.full(y = c(y = 1, z = 1), func = sys, parms = parms)
```

In the function `jacobian.fully()` you can use your steady state results, I just picked random results. The definition of `sys` uses the standard definition for ODEs in the package [`deSolve`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/index.html), an excellent package for solving ODEs.
The result is a normal Jacobian matrix.

So with this definition you can run solving algorithms for your equations, e.g.

```
library(deSolve)
ode <- deSolve::ode(y = c(y = 1, z = 0), 
           times = seq(1,100), 
           func = sys, 
           parms = parms)
plot(ode)
```

I hope this helps you a little bit!
Regards,
J_F

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks. I already knew `rootsolve` but I couldn't figure out how to implement it. Do you have an idea how I could now also find the Jacobian w.r.t. as this would be needed to linearise this system around the steady state.

Comment: you mean w.r.t. `u`?

Comment: To clarify what I'm after. I have a system definition as in `sys` with the dynamic variables `x[1]` and `x[2]`. Within that definition there's also the time-dependent function `u`. First I want to calculate the Jacobian w.r.t. `x` for a constant `u` and then the Jacobian w.r.t `u` for `x` set to steady state.